# m3ph1st0s's programming puzzle 1 (C++)

Tags: code-challenge, programming-puzzle

This is the first of a series of C++ puzzles for you. Hope you will enjoy.

So, puzzle no.1:

Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

Insert some code on a single new line anywhere inside the program so that the output will be 0. The new line will contain AT MOST 18 characters (including spaces), and the rest of the lines will remain unmodified.
 To be clear, here is an example of a valid new code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   int* p = NULL;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

A new line with 15 characters was inserted so it's ok. However it does not solve the problem.

If this is too simple for you, don't worry, more is coming!!

Comment: I'm very happy someone posts a C++ question occasionally! I mean, with all the puzzles where a C++ solution would be 20 or 30 lines, then people posting solutions in J or K or Golfscript becomes frustrating after a while.

Comment: Does the result have to be valid, well-defined C++ or can it use UB? (But like Mr Lister noted, the original code isn’t even valid C++.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I don't know what IDE you use, I used DevC++ and it worked fine, so i wouldn't really say it's not valid C++ :) And the result has to be valid also, yes.

Comment: it is not valid. main must return int (read the c++ standard)

Comment: we are missing the point here. put an int and a return 0 if you mind, I didn't.

Comment: @Bogdan: Dafuq? For one, DevC++ is so unspeakably ancient, it's output is irrelevant. And secondly, whether or not any given compiler in any given configuration at any time targetting any OS accepts it does not make it valid C++.

Comment: Nice task, but the limit of only 18 characters forbids a lot of creative solutions. What's the point? It's obvious that those short `#define` ones work, but they aren't really the most interesting ones, are they?

Comment: While I find the idea very nice, **there is no scoring criteria**.

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for all the feedback and the advice, since this was my first post I did make some mistakes (like ignoring the int and not mentioning 0 as the ONLY output) but I promise I'll learn out of your advice and next time it will be more precise! Cheers

Comment: @leftaroundbout: I limited the size of the line because I wanted to deny the most obvious solution: std::cout<<0; exit(0);

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru: Maybe it would be better to forbid it more explicitly, i.e. "the `main` function must run all of its body" or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#define int float
```

should work as well and is the same length.

Comment: this is what I had in mind when I first came with the idea

Comment: `#define int float` is actually undefined behavior. You are not allowed to give keywords new meaning.

Comment: Fred, can you cite your sources? The GCC cpp docs say "You may define any valid identifier as a macro, even if it is a C keyword."

Comment: @Dan: The C++ Standard forbids it.

Comment: @DeadMG Well, it doesn't forbid it, as the standard does **not** forbid UB. _But_ you end up with undefined behaviour...

Comment: _should work as well and is the same length_ error:
'::main' must return 'int' (minGW 4.4) but `#define float int` works fine

Comment: You'd have to make it the first line of your main, after main is defined...

Comment: @Dan In such case it works, sorry.

Comment: I tried this. It works as long as it is defined after int main().

Comment: It may be UB, but several popular compilers support it anyway.  I've done `#define int ERROR` to force myself to use the equivalent of `int32_t` instead of built-in types.  By the time I got around to `int main()`, I had forgotten about the macro and wondered why the heck my code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 35):

We can get rid of a=1 by moving it into another scope:

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
int a=0;if(0)
    const int a=1;
    const int b=2;
    const float c=0.5;
    std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

This is I think 13 characters. Or better yet get a new `a` that also results in 0:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
if(int a=2)
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

That's 11 characters

Answer (score 24):

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
   const int a=1;
#define a 0
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

1 new line, 12 new chars

Comment: That's what I wanted to submit... +1 for you.

Comment: My first idea when read the question)))

Answer (score 23):

So, `#define a 0`, Done. I saw that was posted - unsurprisingly.

Surprisingly, this wasn't posted:

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout<<0||
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

*14 chars*

That should do, right?

Answer (score 22):

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
const int a=0;//\
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

17 chars.

By the way, the original program doesn't compile under MSVC, which complains that `main` doesn't have a return type.

Comment: int a=0;//\ will also do the trick

Comment: Absolutely. But is this a "shortest line wins" kind of contest?

Comment: I thought so, but it's not. Nice trick by the way

Comment: Yes, shortest solution wins on codegolf SE. see [faq](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Hi, like I said I used DevC++ so I didn't mind about main's return type :)

Comment: @BЈовић the FAQ says the shortest solution wins for actual code-golf questions. This question is not clearly a code-golf question.

Comment: multi-line comment - great trick!

Answer (score 12):

18, including newline

```
#define float int
```

Comment: I'm not really sure this works...ur declaring c as a float and initializing it with 0.5

Comment: Which will truncate to zero.

Comment: you're right, funny thing I've never come across initializing an int with decimal value, I'd thought it would be compiler error, but it only issues a warning

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru take a gander at the C++ standard, it specifically details the implicit conversion at play here.

Comment: Note that although all compilers allow this, the standard prohibits redefining keywords (and `float` is a keyword).

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   1?std::cout<<0:
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

15 chars.

Comment: will output more than a "0"

Comment: why the ternary operator wouldn't work?

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
#define a 0;1
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

14 characters.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>
main()
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
std::cout<<0;//\
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

It's 17 characters so it just fits.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>
main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   return puts("0");
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

17 chars.

Comment: Best solution yet, because it flies in the face of anything related to C++.

Comment: `puts´ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @shiona what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Ashrr gcc (g++) 4.5.4

Comment: If you use `return write(1,"0",1);` it compiles under g++ ok

Comment: @gnibbler it's too long for solution, though.

Comment: Don't think, this code returns 0. But you can replace space via exclamation mark. Anyway, I'm not sure when puts returns zero.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know C++, however based on the question, couldn't you just input a line to simply output 0? the question specifies the output should be 0, it does not specify you must CHANGE the output to 0.

```
std::cout << 0
```

(I have 0 clue on C++, perhaps somebody can use this concept though)

Comment: Oh well, the output should be just 0, I thought it was obvious, otherwise there would be no puzzle, would it?

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru You will find that exploiting a poorly written question is a common technique to solving these puzzles. If you want to prevent users from taking these shortcuts, spend a few extra minutes analyzing your own question and try to remove any potential ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

12 chars, similar to mob's solution

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
#define a b
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

other combinations also work, like `#define a c` or `#define c 0`

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), but I seem to be wearing that hat today!

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
```

## --a;

```
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

five chars, including the newline;

Comment: This does not compile, because `a` is `const`.

Comment: Oops, I should have given it to a compiler!  :-(

Answer (score 0):

c++ whatever...

```
echo "0"; exit
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

run via:

```
sh mp.cpp
```

Comment: Nice try but violates the requirement: valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on [Mr Lister's answer](/a/8513) but slightly less obvious.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const float a=1; //??/
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
int a;if(a)
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

How about these 11 chars...

Comment: The problem here is that the `int a` before the `if` is not being initialized, so `a` could have any value.

Comment: This is undefined, you’re using an uninitialised value for `a`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define a 0
```

http://codepad.org/N06weGJc

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   const int a=1;
   const int b=2;
   const float c=0.5;
#define a 0
   std::cout << a/b-a*c;
}
```

Comment: Ups.. Posted the answer before looking the others. There is already the same answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8507/32091